# Change knockout a href data-bind to link to image

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs, fancybox

Is there anyway to change this href to image url?
Its from Magento Checkout module copied to my theme Magento_Checkout/web/template/minicart/item/default.html

```
<a data-bind="attr: {href: product_url, title: product_name}" tabindex="-1" class="product-item-photo" data-fancybox>
    <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('itemImage') -->
    <!-- ko template: {name: getTemplate(), data: item.product_image} --><!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
</a>
```

I was trying to change to this:

```
<a data-bind="attr: {href: product_image, title: product_name}"
```

but no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this

```
<a data-bind="attr: {href: item.product_image.src, title: product_name}" tabindex="-1" class="product-item-photo">
```

Comment: It's works, perfect Thank You. It was also working when I overwrite /vendor/magento/module-checkout/CustomerData/DefaultItem.php in my theme adding new parametr 'img_src' => $imageHelper->getUrl()  but whats the point adding new if there is one. Thanks